# Navigation ignores comment blocks in (La)TeX mode

Tags: latex, comment, navigation, tex-mode

I sometimes leave large blocks of comments in LaTeX source code:

```
Text text text text.

% Comments comments comments comments.
% Six lines of comments.
% More comments.

% Separate comment block.
% Eight lines of comments.
% More comments.

More text.
```

Navigating within these comment blocks can be difficult, because emacs
acts as though they were not there at all; <kbd>C-up</kbd>
(`backward-paragraph`) and <kbd>C-down</kbd> (`forward-paragraph`) skip
past any number of comments and blank lines, and the cursor ends up past
the next block of text lines.

I would like emacs to treat such comment blocks exactly as it treats
normal text, so that C-up and C-down will stop on blank lines between
comment lines and regular text, or between comment lines.

I looked at `tex-mode.el`. There's a macro named `tex-search-noncomment`
that seems related to this, but I'm not sure what to do about it. My
elisp-fu is very weak.

I'm using emacs 23.4.1.

Comment: AUCTeX works exactly in the way you like.

Comment: @giordano Hmm, sounds like something I should try, for more reasons than this. Thanks.